# Input buttons randomly floating

Tags: asp.net, css

I am having this issue with an input button on IE7 that is used to search for a product (as you can guess from the image) for some reason in IE7 this button is being thrown into random places and not sticking to the set position that it should. This only happens in IE7, not any browser, so I was curious if anyone knew why it would be doing this? (Also IE7 support is not my choice, has to be done.)

[image: Correct Button]
  [image: Incorrect Button]

My Css:

```
dl#Navigation input.Button {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
border: 2px solid #3B9BD9;
color: #000000;
}
dl#Navigation input.Smallest {
cursor: pointer;
width: auto;
}
```

Html:

```
    <dt>Search Products<br />
    <web:SearchTextBox runat="server" id="SearchKeyword" class="Text" />
    <web:SearchSubmit ID="SearchSubmit1" runat="server" SearchBoxes="SearchKeyword" Text="Go" URL="~/catalogue/results.aspx" Class="Smallest Button" />
    </dt>
```

Comment: can't tell without seeing your css

Comment: Added it in, hope that helps.

Comment: post the html too. Better would be a jSfiddle link

Comment: the html is pretty irrelevant :P but I will.

Comment: Your provided code works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/S2SFN/1/. Reproduce the problem in a shareable environemnt (eg. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)) and then post it in your question

Comment: Thank's that's a reall ynice tool. I actually fixed the issue, it was two styles overlapping each other.

Comment: @NortonTaylor yeah, it is a great supporter to questions. If you have found an answer then you can add it to this question and accept it in 48hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the things I'd suggest doing is to check that the parent container (which is somehow is a `dt` here) has a proper width to hold both elements and then set the `width` property to the `input` element.

However there are some other ways of positioning the elements and achieving the same result. Using `floats` for instance would do the same effect. Use `float: left` on both elements (`input` and `button`). But to do so, you need to understand the peculiarities of floats and how to deal with them.

P.s. Another piece of advice concerning your sample css code would be to review your selectors. Try putting the following css instead of yours and nothing will change (hopefully :) ), but the efficiency of the **selectors** is better

```
#Navigation .Button {
    background: #FFF;
    border: 2px solid #3B9BD9;
    color: #000;
}
#Navigation .Smallest {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```